# ERROR on Wix v4: "The Package element contains an unexpected child element 'LaunchCondition'."

Tags: compiler-errors, wix4

Hope to find you all well!

I'm creating a Wix v4 MSI Project to make an Windows Service Installer, and I can't fix this compiler error:

```
WIX0005 The Package element contains an unexpected child element 'LaunchCondition'.
```

My Package file (Package.wxs) start as follows:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" 
     xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
    <Package Name="Serviço de Gestão de Ativos" 
             Language="1033" 
             Codepage="1252"
             Version="0.9.0.2" 
             Manufacturer="Grupo Data"  
             UpgradeCode="some-update-guid" 
             InstallerVersion="200">
        
        <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK48" />
        <LaunchCondition Condition="NOT NETFRAMEWORK48" Message="!(loc.LanchCondition)" />
(...)
```

I tried to use "Condition" element as well, but did not work. I don't know where to find answers, 'cause Wix v4 documentation is a bit confused.

Any help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element isn't `LaunchCondition` -- you want `Launch`: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/launch/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know where I read it should be the name of the element. It may be a mix of "Launch" and "Condition".
Anyway, it was really helpful!